# XMLHTTPrequests in Javascript/PHP with input parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am banging my head against the wall with this one. The answer to my question should be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064691/how-do-i-pass-along-variables-with-xmlhttprequest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494437/passing-a-javascript-variable-to-php-with-xmlhttprequest), and I don't want to post a duplicate. But for some reason, my code, though seemingly exactly the same as these examples, won't work.

I'm trying to pass an ID from a Javascript function to a PHP function via an xmlhttprequest. Here is my Javascript function:

```
function acceptRequest(id_Request)
{
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "acceptRequest.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
        alert("Request accepted.");
    };
};
xhttp.send("id_Request="+id_Request);
}
```

My PHP file, acceptRequest.php, looks like this:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id_Request'];
?>
```

What happens is that the Javascript function does send the alert: "Request accepted." But, the PHP function doesn't echo anything out. What am I missing here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your function isn't passing any id. I'm sure in your php/javascript. The id you want to pass is in some input box.

Then in your js function, you can say

Var id = document.getElementById("id-of_input").value;

You can then append this to you Ajax request.

I also noticed that your Ajax get no response from the php.

```
 if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&.      xmlhttp.status == 200){
   document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

}

In your case, it'ld be xhttp.responseText;

That line just means where you wish to display the results of the Ajax request.

Comment: This makes sense, but even if I have it echo "test" or some other constant, it still does not print anything.

Comment: I see the problem. In your php script, not the one conned to your Ajax request. The response is going no where create a div,and give it an id. Now in your js function, where the code say if xhttp=4&200... put this code inside that statement, var theDiv = document.getElementById("id_of_the_new_div"). Then theDiv.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText; now you can get a reply from the Ajax php.

Comment: Code, modified... hope you find it useful